# error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java

I am a complete beginner to java and this is a current project for my class. Though this might be a simple "in your face" problem, I would like some help so I would know in the future.

These are the errors I am getting:

> DogTrack.java:77:        error: illegal start of expression
>       public String showWinners(){
>
> DogTrack.java:77:        error: ';' expected
>       public String showWinners(){

I don't understand on line 77 that I can't start with that, but I started something similar with "public String showTrack()"

This is my current code:

```js
public class DogTrack{
 
  int s = 0; 
  int r = 0; 
  int f = 0; 
  int d = 0; 
 
    public void playGame(){
    while (isOver()==false){
      spin();
      moveRover();
      spin();
      moveSpot();
      spin();
      moveFido();
      showTrack();
    }
 
    if (isOver()==true){
      showTrack();
      showWinners();
    }
  }
 
   public int spin(){
    return ((1+ (int)Math.random()*5));
  }  
 
  public void moveRover(){
    r = r + spin();  
  }
 
  public void moveSpot(){
    s = s + spin();
  }
 
  public void moveFido(){
    f = f + spin();
  }
 
  public boolean isOver(){
    if
      (r >= (d - 1) || s >= (d - 1) || f >= (d -1)) 
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
 
  public String showTrack(){
    String rover = ""; 
    for (int x = 0; x < d; x++){
      if
        (r >= x)
        rover = rover + "R";
      else 
        rover = rover + "o";
    }
 
 
    String spot = ""; 
    for (int x = 0; x < d; x++){
      if
        (s >= x)
        spot = spot + "S";
      else
        spot = spot + "o";
    }
 
      String fido = ""; 
      for (int x = 0; x < d; x++){
      if
        (f >= x)
        fido = fido + "F";
      else
        fido = fido + "o";
    }
    public String showWinners(){
    if (r>=(d-1))
    return "Rover Wins!"; 
    if (s>=(d-1)) 
    return "Spot Wins!"; 
    if (f>=(d-1)) 
    return "Fido Wins!"; 
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `showWinners` method is *inside* of your `showTrack` method, instead of just after it.

Near the end you'll see:

```
    }
    }
}
```

Move one of those close braces to just before `public String showWinners(){`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Though I have tried that before and it did got rid of errors but also came up with two new ones.
(I got rid of one of those three close braces and added another one above "public String showWinners(){)
The two new errors were saying that I was missing a return statement on the line where i made the new close brace and where I deleted the old close brace.